# Track in app events with Mobile App Tracking SDK iOS

Tags: ios, sdk

I am supposed to measure in app events in my iOS app using Mobile App Tracking SDK (MAT). I downloaded and integrated the SDK and created my mobile app in the MAT main page. I got a tracking link for the app and it works. I got a few predefined events with in the profile as well.

I created a test profile using (https://developers.mobileapptracking.com/creating-test-profile/) and tried testing the app using (https://developers.mobileapptracking.com/testing-mobile-app/), but the test profile doesn't seem connected to my mobile app in the MAT profile page.

Now, what I really want to do is measure some custom inApp events such as 'Signup', 'Signin' etc. I have searched allot and experimented with the events but I cant seem to find a useful link as to what I need to do to get my custom events. I know there is some crucial connection between MAT profile and my app that I'm missing. Do i register these events on the MAT profile?
And what exactly is the 'Publisher' tab for?

I am sorry if these questions sound very lame, I am a newbie and this is the first time I'm integrating such an SDK and the over all process seems very complicated. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a) Custom events:** For using custom events you need firstly create event on the MAT profile (web service).
Go to "Mobile Apps" -> Select your app -> Press "Add Event" button. As result you will see new event with unique Event Id. You should use it in iOS project to track this event:

```
[MobileAppTracker initializeWithMATAdvertiserId:kMATAdvertiserId MATConversionKey:kMATConversionKey];
[MobileAppTracker setAppleAdvertisingIdentifier:[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier]
                     advertisingTrackingEnabled:[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled]]; 
[MobileAppTracker measureSession];
[MobileAppTracker measureAction:@"EventId"];
```

Links to documentation:

- http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/23745301-iOS-SDK-v3-2-Quick-Start
- http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/26861970-Measuring-In-App-Events-with-the-SDK#usage

**b) Publishers:** You need use publishers if you use third parties companies for your app marketing. One company or site is one publisher. Then you could you MAT statistics to calculate publisher effectiveness or any other parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I somehow started receiving my app events in my MAT profile. I think I added my iPad's IFV to the test profile and thats why the events are getting accepted.

    'MobileAppTracker *matTracker = [MobileAppTracker sharedManager];'

This code doesn't work for me. Do I need to write this method myself? The MobileAppTracker.h doesnot contain any such declaration. Or any of the other methods that you wrote in your code snippet. I was generating events using:    [MobileAppTracker measureAction:@"Dashboard Visit"];

Comment: No, you needn't add this method by yourself. It seems that you have new version of MAT sdk and these methods are deprecated.

Comment: I have version 3.1.3.
Could you guide me as to how to collect events in my live app? I mean the test profile I created asked for my device's IFV. How do you cater for that in the live app? I just plug in the advertiserId and conversionKey in my appDelegate and the events will be received under my mobile app in the web profile?

Although the log section in the Reports main section shows up empty. The events from  my app I have received under the Mobile Apps subsection.

Comment: I have updated my root anwer here with actual code for new sdk version and links to documentation. I hope it will help you.

Comment: This is how I was originally doing it. Thanks though. Much appreciated :)